# Multitouch + Scrolling do not work on Acer 4741

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, mouse-scroll

My laptop is an Acer 4741. It's running Ubuntu 11.10

When I worked on Windows 7, my touch pad had vertical and horizontal scrolling and multi-gesture. Both scrolling and multi-gesture aren't working on Ubuntu.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Start the **System Settings** (e.g. via the button in the top right corner -> System Settings) and the go to **Mouse and Touchpad**. There select Touchpad. This tab offers you to enable two-finger scrolling and also horizontal scrolling.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: BTW, my touchpad is ALPS